# Control of parallelization

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am running a custom processor on a rowset that does not seem to run in parallel. The underlying ~1GB text file is first read into a table that is partitioned via round robin. The 'Extract' runs on 200 vertices but then (under 'Aggregate' node) the processing [that does various complex computations] happens on only 2 vertices even though the parallelism parameter is much higher than that. Is there a special hint that needs to be used to dictate the compiler to use more vertex? Is there a function or property that needs to be overridden to set the parallelism at this phase as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply. But it is vacation time :).

It is good to see that the extract phase is fully scaled out.

Without seeing the script or the generated plan it is a bit difficult to say why you only see 2 vertices in some places. There are a couple of reasons why that may be the case:

1. you don't have enough data to scale out to more.
2. your aggregation needs more data and thus the plan has less parallelism.
3. your operation is intrinsically less parallel.
4. The optimizer's data cardinality estimation is off and chooses not enough parallelism. We have some ability to hint, but I rather first see the job.

Note that custom processors often block the optimizer from pushing optimizations through in the script (using the READ ONLY option for example helps) and can throw off the cardinality estimations.

If you send me the script, the job graph and the link to the job to mrys at Microsoft, I and the team will look into it next week after the holidays are over.

Comment: I noticed that I left this question unanswered so let me close the loop to update the community on the resolution. Since compiler does not have visibility into what custom processor is doing it is harder to parallelize and this should be your last resort. I brought what custom processor was doing to inline u-sql c# instructions as much as I possibly can and saw an observable difference. Thanks Michael!

Comment: Great to hear! And if you can avoid doing custom processors by moving the code into UDFs, you normally get better performance and scale.